# Trouble with linking boost::python::numpy

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost, undefined-symbol

I wrote a small example to show what's going on.

my_test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;
int my_Foo() 
{
    Py_Initialize();
    np::initialize();
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    return 0;
}
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_test)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("my_Foo", my_Foo);
}
```

py_test.py

```
import my_test as t
t.my_Foo();
```

I compile all with command :

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -o my_test.so my_test.cpp -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7
```

And I get this error :

```
ImportError: /home/my_test.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python5numpy10initializeEb
```

And it works when I comment this line

```
//np::initialize();
```

I have no idea how to fix it. I have read similar questions on the forum, but none of the solutions helped me. I tried update boost, update python, link libraries, put generated module before other module during compilation - nothing helps. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Bionic
`-lboost_python` is not enough. You are missing `-lboost_numpy`.

On Xenial you won't find prebuilt libraries yet:

```
sudo apt -y install libpython2.7-dev libboost-python-dev
git clone https://github.com/ndarray/Boost.NumPy
cd Boost.Numpy
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make 
sudo make install
```

replace in your code `boost/python/numpy.hpp` with `boost/numpy.hpp` also replace `namespace np = boost::python::numpy` with `namespace np = boost::numpy`;                                                    |

```
g++ -o test5.so -fPIC -shared test5.cpp -lboost_python -lboost_numpy -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7/ -I/usr/include/python2.7
enter code here

 ~> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib64 ldd test5.so 
   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe9cd36000)
   libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0 (0x00007ffba47bd000)
   libboost_numpy.so => /usr/local/lib64/libboost_numpy.so (0x00007ffba45a2000)
   libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ffba4216000)
   libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffba3ffe000)
   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffba3c34000)
   libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffba3a17000)
   libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007ffba3489000)
   libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffba3180000)
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffba4c11000)
   libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ffba2f66000)
   libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffba2d62000)
   libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ffba2b5f000)
```

Comment: I tried but I get error : /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_numpy

Comment: what system are you on? if it's a debian flavour: `sudo apt -y install libboost-numpy-dev`

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

Comment: I get error : unable to locate package libboost-numpy-dev

Comment: that was a little tricky and needed access to a 16.04. did it through openvpn / ssh from iphone on a train from cologne to berlin. life has become so awesome.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still get the same import error :( Only diffrence is that now I have dir `numpy` and file `numpy.hpp` in `/usr/local/include/boost`. The same files I had in `/usr/include/boost/python`.

Comment: and you ran the make install and added ` -lboost_numpy`. I added the output of `ldd`

Comment: `g++ -o my_test.so -fPIC -shared my_test.cpp -lboost_python -lboost_numpy -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7/ -I/usr/include/python2.7` now i get error `libboost_numpy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: add `-L/usr/local/lib64`. That's where `make install` put the missing library, that was giving you the headaches.

Comment: I also added `-L/usr/local/lib64` and still the same. Output of ldd is also the same as yours.

Comment: There u go. Would appreciate, if you accepted the answer

Comment: U had an issue building. I helped. If there is a problem using it, you should open a new issue. I helped a good deal.

Comment: you need to add libboost_numpy.so to search path of you python. maybe /usr/local/lib.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib64 python` then you module can be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem when linking for python3 or above.
In that case what helped is to add those linking options:

`-lboost_python3 -lboost_numpy3`

Apparently `-lboost_numpy` is not found, thus we need to use `-lboost_numpy3`

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure your python version and boost version.
my version:
`python2.7`
`boost1.67`

---

If the `cmakeList.txt` is:

```
link_libraries(${Pangolin_LIBRARIES}
               boost_python
               boost_numpy
               assimp
               util)
```

so change it to

```
link_libraries(${Pangolin_LIBRARIES}
               boost_python27
               boost_numpy27
               assimp
               util)
```

because:

> The Boost.Python library names now contain the Python version suffix. A variant compiled with Python 2.7 will thus produce library names boost_python27 and boost_numpy27, etc., making it possible to host variants for multiple Python versions next to each other.([from here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/python/doc/html/rn.html))
>   you can check your boost library path.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to compile and link the code given by OP with Boost 1.71.0 and Python 3.5 via the following command:

```
g++ -o my_test.so -fPIC -shared my_test.cpp \
-I/usr/include/python3.5  `# for pyconfig.h` \
-L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu  `# for libpython3.5 or libpython3.5m` \
-lpython3.5  \
-I/usr/local/boost_1_71_0/include  `# for Boost header files` \
-L/usr/local/boost_1_71_0/lib  `# for Boost binary files` \
-lboost_python35 -lboost_numpy35
```

On my Linux system (Debian Stretch), the Boost library is placed in `/usr/local/boost_1_71_0`.